# Uniform convergence of a sequence of composite functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ are two sequences of polynomials on $[0,1]$. Each $f_n$ has nonnegative coefficients so that it is an increasing and differentiable function. Furthermore, assume that the following holds:

(1) for every $n$, $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n(1)=1$;

(2) the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on every subinterval of $[0,1)$ to the function $f$ where $f(x)=0$ for $0 \leq x < 1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x=1$;

(3) for every $n$, $g_n(0)=0$ and $g_n(1) = \alpha < 1$. Also $g_n(x) \leq 1 - f_n ^{-1}(x)$, $\forall x \in [0,1)$. Here $f_n ^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $f_n$;

(4) the sequence $\{g_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on every closed subinterval of $[0,1)$; further assume that there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ that diverges to infinity so that $g_n(x) \leq x^{a_n}$.

The question is: does it hold that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n\big(f_n ^{-1}(x) + g_n(x)\big) = x,
\end{equation}
either pointwise or uniformly for $x$ in every subinterval of $[0,1)$? If it is true, how to prove the statement? If there is a counterexample, what condition should I add in order to make the conclusion hold? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that your functions $g_n$, $f_n$ and  $f_n^{-1}$ are continuous on $[0,1]$. Hence letting $x\to 1$, $x<1$ in your condition (3), you get $g_n(1)\leq 1-f_n^{-1}(1)=0$. Hence $g_n(1)=0$, and this imply $g_n(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$ as an increasing function.

Comment: @Kelenner Not sure how you get $g_n(1)=0$ for every $n$. Individual functions are continuous, but the limiting ones are not.

Comment: My comment was only for a fixed $n$. So you use only the continuity in $x$.

Comment: @Kelenner I see. I should have said that the $g_n$ are polynomials with not necessarily nonnegative coefficients. This has been changed. But given this, do you think the statement is correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A new example: if I am not wrong,  you can put $f_n(x)=x^n$ and $g_n(x)=\alpha(x^n+x(1-x)/n)$, with a fixed $\alpha<0$, study $(\root{n}\of{x}+\alpha x^n+\alpha x(1-x)/n)^n$, and for $0<x<1$, this  converge to $x\exp(\alpha x(1-x))$, not to $x$.

Comment: @Kelenner I agree. I think $g_n(x)$ should converge to zero exponentially fast in order to make the claim true. In your example, expressions like $(x^{1/n} + x^{\sqrt{n}})^n$ converges to $x$.